# Azure Deploy Center add GitHub source - organization, repo and branch is missing or wrong

Tags: azure, github, deployment, cicd

I am trying to deploy my application in Azure through its Deployment Center.
I went to `App Service -> Deployment Center` in Azure and chose source `GitHub` and logged into my account. Then I cannot choose my organization, I see only my GitHub account name(repository and branch aren't available at all).
[Screenshot of Azure form][1].
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAcMG.png

I know that it's not GitHub issue because I have another environment where I have selected correct organization, repo and branch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.